# How do I retrieve information from an ODATA result into JavaScript variables?

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, odata

I'm working with SharePoint to create a button that you can click to retrieve a list entry from a list created on that SharePoint and populate a series of text areas based on what's retrieved.  This will then be used to either edit and send back, or to populate into an html formatted template to email out.

So far, I have the ODATA call:

```
function retrieveData(){
var incidentID = document.getElementById("IncidentRef");

var requestUri = "https://site/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Incident List')/Items?$Filter=Title eq '" + incidentID + "'&$select=Title,Id,ImpactedArea,IncidentStatus,Impact,AdvisorActions,Update";
}
```

From this, I can get an XML response, which is displaying everything I'm wanting to retrieve from the list successfully - what I'm not sure how to do is to transfer it from the ODATA XML response and into JavaScript variables that I can then assign to the `.value` of the various text areas I have set up to display this info.  I've read that you can retrieve the data as a JSON file - will this store the data in the console so I can pull it from there?  If so, how do you retrieve data from this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example code for your reference.

```
<input id="IncidentRef" type="text"/><input type="button" value="GetItem" onclick="getListItem()"/>
<p>Title: <input id="Title" type="text"/></p>
<p>ImpactedArea: <input id="ImpactedArea" type="text"/></p>
<p>IncidentStatus: <input id="IncidentStatus" type="text"/></p>
<p>Impact: <input id="Impact" type="text"/></p>
<p>AdvisorActions: <input id="AdvisorActions" type="text"/></p>
<p>Update: <input id="Update" type="text"/></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getListItem(){
    var listName="Incident List";
    var incidentID = $("#IncidentRef").val();
    if(incidentID!=""){
        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listName+"')/items?$filter=Title eq '" + incidentID + "'&$select=Title,Id,ImpactedArea,IncidentStatus,Impact,AdvisorActions,Update",
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.d.results.length>0){
                    var item=data.d.results[0];
                    $("#Title").val(item.Title);
                    $("#ImpactedArea").val(item.ImpactedArea);
                    $("#IncidentStatus").val(item.IncidentStatus);
                    $("#Impact").val(item.Impact);
                    $("#AdvisorActions").val(item.AdvisorActions);
                    $("#Update").val(item.Update);
                }                
            },
            error: function (data) {
                //alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }    
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the above code! I've altered it a bit more to include the other elements I had to remove from my example, however I'm getting a script error once this has been moved across to my html doc:

```SCRIPT5009: 'getListItem' is not defined```

This is appearing to advise that the button's ```onclick``` function isn't a function name, however I've copied the call across and I still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

To get JSON, add the following as a header in your REST request. (Are you using jQuery AJAX, or ... ?)

```
{"accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"}
```

or any of these:

```
{"accept": "application/json; odata=minimalmetadata"}

{"accept": "application/json; odata=nometadata"}
```